# Новые бейджи в профиле участника enSO

Tags: обсуждение

Сегодня глянул один из профилей на en so - у них какие-то отдельные иконки появились над блоком меток:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У нас скоро такие же "красноармейские" блоки добавят?

Comment: Несколько неожиданно видеть жирную эмблему там, где знаков вовсе нет.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ мне тоже интересно, как они это "high" resolution иконку вместят в 32x32 (условно). само отображение профиля под постами изменят 100%, ведь красная армия всех сильней; не красноармейцы будут прогибаться под фронтэндеров, а фронтэндеры будут прогибаться под советов! 

Comment: Появились, теперь нужно доперевести)

Answer (score 9):

Соответствующий вопрос [на Общей Мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366800/383809): выставлен статус: [статус-отложено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be).

[*Выжимка* ответа от работника Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366832/383809):

> В наших планах (backlog) развернуть это на все сообщества, пока
> выставляем [статус-отложено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) так как данная задача не входит
> в **текущий и на настоящий момент распланированные** спринты.
> Вышеупомянутый пост планируется обновлять по изменении статуса задачи.

Answer (score 0):

На enSO много всего такого, чего нет (и может никогда не будет) на других сайтах сети. При этом повлиять как либо на планы добавить (или наоборот, не добавлять) некий функционал с enSO на ruSO мы практически не можем. Даже КМ забил (не по своей воле, конечно, я надеюсь) на ruSO. На отдалённость ruSO от основной линии развития SE, безусловно, влияет и язык участников. Чтобы быть услышанным, и получить какую-то реакцию от власть(код) имущих нужно как минимум обращаться на MSE. Чисто пообсуждать фичи сайта-родоначальника, наверное, можно, но выхлопа от этого практически никакого не будет. Разве, что кто-то, кто не посещает enSO узнает о том, что там иначе, чем на ruSO. Но что ему даст такое знание? Уйдёт на enSO за новыми "фишками"? Возрадуется, что этого "ужаса" нет на ruSO? Сложно сказать. Формально, фича к нашему сайту отношения не имеет (пока?) и вполне можно закрывать как оффтоп. Хотя при скудной жизни Меты ruSO даже такие посты хоть как-то разбавляют ситуацию.