# Отсутствует перевод в новых "медалях" в профиле пользователя

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки, профиль-участника

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(без бронзовых бейджей пока никого не нашел)

Строки:

- [gold badges](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5Egold%20badges%24&translationStatus=2)
- [silver badges](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5Esilver%20badges%24&translationStatus=2)
- [bronze badges](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5Ebronze%20badges%24&translationStatus=2)
- [This user doesn’t have any gold/silver/bronze badges yet.](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=This%20user%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20have%20any%20(gold%7Csilver%7Cbronze)%20badges%20yet&translationStatus=2)
- [You don't have a bronze/silver/gold badge yet...](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=You%20don%5B%E2%80%99%27%5Dt%20have%20a%20(bronze%7Csilver%7Cgold)%20badge%20yet.&translationStatus=2)
- [Browse questions](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5EBrowse%20questions%24)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Новые бейджи в профиле участника enSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11595/1365)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Утвердил и немного упростил предложенные переводы.

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая  rev 2021.8.4.39914

Comment: Последние тоже посмотрите плиз (которые "You don't have a bronze/silver/gold badge yet...")

Comment: @insolor их тоже утвердил, только "метки" на "знаки" поменял :) Вообще, конечно, странные предложения там в оригинале. Заработать золотой знак, написав ответ с рейтингом 100. Есть другие более лёгкие пути.

Comment: Еще добавил перевод для "Browse questions": https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4PDr.png (снимок с rus.meta.stackexchange.com). Когда нет бронзовых знаков теоретически тоже какая-то кнопка может быть, но не могу посмотреть что за текст, у меня везде как минимум один бронзовый знак есть (автобиограф).

Comment: @insolor по кнопке в бронзовом блоке спросил [комментом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366800/when-will-the-new-stack-overflow-badge-design-come-to-other-sites#comment1228401_366832). Может что ответят.

Comment: @insolor получил [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366800/when-will-the-new-stack-overflow-badge-design-come-to-other-sites/366832?noredirect=1#comment1228481_366832), добавил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16278).